# Is it possible to hide some fields based on user role in elasticsearch v 5.6.6?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I need to hide some fields from any find result in elasticsearch for non-admin users. For example object below exists in elasticsearch database

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "login": "john",
  "password": "123"
}
```

And if user login with admin role, he can see field `password` but if user has role 'simple_user' he can only see

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "login": "john"
}
```

Is it possible to make it without x-pack premium licence?

Comment: Where does your user log into? You don't have X-pack security right?

Comment: Now option xpack.security.enabled = false and x-pack isn't installed

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: Yes, you can use source filtering: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html  You have to build your request and the _source[field to keep...] according to your user level.